# Adapting custom class to be compatible with CoreData

Tags: swift, class, core-data, enums, nsmanagedobject

I read a few CoreData tutorials and Apple's Documentation, but I still haven't found one thing: how to fully integrate CoreData with a custom class.

Say I have the custom class `Dog` and I checked "Include CoreData" when creating the project.

The dog has a couple properties like `name`, `legsNumber` and some enums like `vaccinationStatus` with the cases `.Vaccinated` and `.NotVaccinated`.

From what I understand the only way is to create a new file and adapt the code. I have to create an `NSManagedObject` subclass and assign it to an entity (Dog in this case) from the `.xdatamodeld` file. Then it creates 2 files `Dog+CoreDataProperties.swift` and `Dog.swift`.

And I should add in `Dog+CoreDataProperties.swift` the properties that I want the dog to have, like `@NSManaged var name: String` and `legsNumber`, but what about the enum?

Can it be like this?

```
@NSManaged enum VaccinationStatus {
    case Vaccinated
    case NotVaccinated
    }
```

Can I add another class inside it with properties? Like an array with, say the brand names and prices of each dog's clothes (kinda extreme, but you understand what I meant). Or do I have to add another entity and create another `NSManagedObject` file and add `NSManaged` properties to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would create the model, add all your attributes there and then Xcode would generate the code for you. For your enumerate I'd use an integer or Boolean type in the model (depending on the type of enumerate).

Now, in the classes generated by Xcode you can add additional functions which expose the data of your entity and allow mutation of that data in whatever way you want - just be sure to call the setters and getters that Xcode generates for you.

So in that class you'll define your enumeration, and add functions to set and get the enumeration, and that will convert the supplied enumerate to a boil and store it in the entity. You can use the raw value of the enumerates to help.

You also need to consider how and when you save...

Comment: Could you provide some code? I kept researching but I still haven't found what I wanted. Let's say I have the entity `EmployeeEntity` with Attributes `name` and `dateOfBirth` (String and Date). Each employee can have tasks to accomplish. So that should be another entity `TaskEntity` with Attributes `taskName` and `taskStatusValue`? And add `tasks` as a relationship to `EmployeeEntity` and `employee` to `TaskEntity`? And then I should create the files for both entities? I basically want the end result to be for me to access `employee.task[0].status`. Is the logic above correct?

Comment: And then if I add the code in this tutorial (at the enums section) http://www.jessesquires.com/better-coredata-models-in-swift/ in `Task.swift` am I going to be able to access `employee.task[0].status`?

Comment: yes, your logic sounds good. i haven't had time to look at the tutorial you reference